# Split Function returns <Unmatched closing...> error

Tags: java, string

Is `C#` `Split Function` different from `Java`? Why do I get this error when I tried to split the string with a delimiter?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'
)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1669)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2361)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2403)
... <more stacktrace>
```

Using this code: (tutorial from [String Split](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example))

```
private String GetAccountID(String xStr)
{
    String oText = xStr;
    String[] oValA = oText.split(")");
    String[] oValB = oValA[0].split("(");

    return oValB[1]; 
}
```

Sample Values:

```
AccountID sample values:
      (100) Department
      (100A) Budget
      (12-34F) Others

I want to get 100, 100A, 12-34F from the AccountID.
```

Sample Usage:

```
String AccID = GetAccountID(AccountID);
```

Or do you have another solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One normally would do it by regex replace/find.

```
private String getAccountID(String str)
{
    // ^ start, .* any chars, \\( open parenthesis, ([^)]*) no end parenthesis = $1,
    // \\) end parenthesis, .* $ any chars upto end.

    String accountID = str.replaceFirst("^.*\\(([^)]*)\\).*$", "$1");

    // If no matching, accountID == str.
    return accountID == str ? "" : accountID; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is C# Split Function different from Java?

**Yes**.

The C# version of `Split()` accepts a single string token on which to split the target `string`.

The Java version accepts a *regular expression*. `(` is not a valid regular expression, and so the call to `split()` fails.

To get the functionality you want, you can escape the `(` character like so:

```
String[] oValA = oText.split("\\(");
```

Note the double-slash, to account for the fact that `\` is both the Java and regular expression escape character.

Comment: Thank you for the info sir. Can you help me build an expression for this?